# DBF database conditional join correct syntax DBF - edited

Tags: c#, join, foxpro, dbf

I have 4 tables (ROUTBOM, HARD, MAT, ROUT). In the main table ROUTBOM I have ID, PROD_NO and TYPE columns. I had to select based on TYPE and (ID or PROD_NO). Conditions below. Can this be made with an inner join - with condition before join?

Database is FoxPro

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=VFPOLEDB;Data source=c:\test\Data"))
```

Data:
ROUTBOM

```
id      qty      prod_no    Type    Name
20322   0.15000             2       ???    get name from HARD
        2.00000 0066773     4       ???    get name from ROUT
37500   4.00000             2       ???    get name from HARD
29750   4.00000             1       ???    get name from MAT
```

HARD TABLE

```
ID      NAME
20322   H68NK0005
37500   HAS2-30XX-H HYBRID POWDER
```

MAT TABLE

```
ID      NAME
29750   NEOPRENE (McMASTER 8694K61)
02125   SPRING STEEL STRIP .008'' X .50'' X 60''
```

ROUT TABLE

```
ID      NAME
0066773 L.V. DOOR ARC PROOF J4
000198  DEVEL. L.V. DOOR J4
```

Required output

```
id      qty      prod_no    Type    Name
20322   0.15000             2       H68NK0005
        2.00000 0066773     4       L.V. DOOR ARC PROOF J4
37500   4.00000             2       HAS2-30XX-H HYBRID POWDER
29750   4.00000             1       NEOPRENE (McMASTER 8694K61)
```

Query:

Conditions:

```
if id is not null and type 2 JOIN ROUTBOM.id with MAT.id to get the name of material
if id is not null and type 1 JOIN ROUTBOM.id with HARD.id to get the name of hadware
if id is empty and type 4 JOIN ROUTBOM.prod_no with ROUT.id to get the name of part
```

Can be done in one query ? I do not know where condition have to be applied. Once I make the first JOIN the query bring the whole data from HARD.

Query for row data

```
@"SELECT    
                                    t0.Id, 
                                    t1.Name,
                                    t0.Per_Router,
                                    t0.Prod_No,
                                    t0.Rout_No,
                                    t0.Seq,
                                    t0.Type
                                    FROM {0} t0 , "Routbom", "Hardware", "Material", "Rout");
```

Comment: Your query's `SELECT` clause doesn't specify any columns from `t2`, is this intentional?

Comment: no, it will be added later. I have miss something ID could be null. I have to much records after query

Comment: When is type to ID is null er empty.

Comment: I am very sorry I had to re-edit the entire problem. I am in learning process

Comment: Your select as is 'MAY NOT' work at all. t1 alias is obscure there. Within a script it has a chance to work without an error (but the result should be unpredictable). You need to define your table structures and what you want more detailed IMHO.

Comment: This data and structure is already existent. I now its not working, maybe a general idea of how to put this thing together in one script. Right now I fill a DataTable as show on ROUTBOM output and then for each line based on TYPE I do another query but is long.

Comment: I wrote an SQL for you. I meant data types and structures for other tables and sample data were missing. Anyway I think I got it right already.

Comment: Despite your edits, expected output doesn't match to your rules (MAT and HARD has wrong types?). Anyway you already have the answer. No matching Id in Rout.

Comment: Type 2 is HARD or MAT? You need to set the type correctly only. BTW this is a bad design, sorry.

Comment: Its HARD copy paste when editing... I know its not my design, I have to deal with, and is my platform to learn and test unfortunatly

Comment: Don't worry VFP SQL is not the easiest to work with, but not too much different than ANSI SQL. When you find something hard to do with a single SQL, you can chain multiple SQLs -cursors as results to use in subsequent SQL- and execute that script via 'ExecScript' OR easier create a database and add Stored Procedures to it which end with a 'SetResultSet' function. And also you can use say OpenQuery from SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand from your limited explanation:

```
string sql = @"SELECT Id,Name,Per_Router,Prod_No,Rout_No,Seq,Type
from
(
    Select t0.*, t1.Name as Name 
    from RoutBom t0
    inner join Mat t1 on t0.Id = t1.Id
    where t0.type = 2
    union 
    Select t0.*, t1.Name as Name 
    from RoutBom t0
    inner join Hard t1 on t0.Id = t1.Id
    where t0.type = 1
    union
    Select t0.*, t1.Name as Name 
    from RoutBom t0
    inner join Rout t1 on t0.Prod_no = t1.Id
    where t0.type = 4 and Empty(Nvl(t0.id,''))
) tmp
";
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=VFPOLEDB;Data source=c:\test\Data"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
{
 con.Open();
 tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
// Do something with tbl
```

It might be easier for you to use Linq instead. Check Tom Brother's Linq To VFP and VFP Entity Framework.

This is another way of doing that, and also takes care of the union problem:

```
void Main()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT *, 
    Cast(icase(
    type = '1', (select Name from Mat t1 where t0.Id = t1.Id),
    type = '2', (select Name from Hard t1 where t0.Id = t1.Id),
    empty(nvl(id,'')) and type='4', (select Name from Rout t1 where t0.Prod_No = t1.Id),
    '') as c(100)) as Name
    from RoutBom t0";
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=VFPOLEDB;Data source=c:\Test\Data"))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
    // Do something with tbl
    tbl.Dump(); // you said LinqPad above
}
```

Comment: @busymind, you already have the answer above (edited to correct t1 aliasing). Your sample do not seem to be matching to your rules. You can edit the SQL to match your real rules.

Comment: I am working to test the code. Thank you again Cetin.

Comment: The query is running but ERROR OleDbException: Operation is invalid for a Memo, Blob, General or Picture field.

Comment: @busymind, That means you have a memo field in either RoutBom or Name is memo. I will send you a revised code soon. (you didn't provide datatypes as I said in the beginning :)

Comment: @busymind, you have a uniqueness problem then. Check which subquery is returning more than one. It means that for a given value you have multiple matches. You wouldn't have that problem if id in hard,rout and mat tables were unique.

Comment: Thanks Cetin, again. I will try to break down the query string.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend that you learn the 'standard' SQL basics (not VFP specific) of JOIN.  You can find a pretty good explanation of that at:  [Inner and Outer JOINs in SQL](http://www.datamartist.com/sql-inner-join-left-outer-join-full-outer-join-examples-with-syntax-for-sql-server)

Then apply that to your tables.
Basically you will have 1 'parent' table and 3 'child' tables which are JOINed to the 'parent' via SQL syntax.

VFP SQL syntax is slightly different than 'generic' SQL syntax, but in most cases the 'generic' syntax works fine.

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT ROUTBOM.*,;
      MAT.Name AS Mat_Name,;
      HARD.Name AS Hard_Name,;
      ROUT.Name AS Rout_Name;
   FROM ROUTBOM;
   LEFT JOIN Mat   ON  ROUTBOM.ID = MAT.ID;
   LEFT JOIN Hard   ON  ROUTBOM.ID = HARD.ID;
   LEFT JOIN Rout   ON  ROUTBOM.ID = Rout.ID;
   WHERE < all whatever conditions >;
   INTO CURSOR Results READWRITE

SELECT Results
BROWSE
```

Note that this was just jotted down and not tested, but it is 'BASIC' SQL syntax which you should learn before trying to apply it to a project.

Maybe you might want to go to: [www3schools - SQL SELECT syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)

Good Luck

Comment: Apreciate the response and thank you for. It does not work. I am using liqpad for now, give me only syntax error.

Comment: Cetin - note that I said:   "it is 'BASIC' SQL syntax"   That includes the JOIN, but as you know there are some VFP specific syntax issues with SQL Query syntax and depending on what this individual needs, they might come up in his WHERE clause(s) or elsewhere.  They should get educated on the basics first and then work with VFP where most of the basic syntax will also apply.